# A weak/shared pointer, detect when one user remains, boost

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, weak-references

I want a pointer where I can tell when the reference count is one. Essentially the pointer works like a weak_ptr, but the cleanup needs to be manual. That is, every so often the program goes through a loop of its pointers and checks which ones have only one reference remaining. Some it will clean, others it will retain a while longer (in case somebody needs it again).

Now, I know how to do this using a combination of a custom cleanup function and weak_ptr. I just think the same thing could be accomplished, with simpler code, if I could simply figure out when only one user of the shared_ptr remains.

I know that shared_ptr has a `use_count` function, but it has this ominous note in the docs: *"...not necessarily efficient. Use only for debugging and testing purposes..."* Naturally I'm not so keen on using something with such a warning.  I don't really need the count anyway, just a way to detect when there is only one left.

Is there some boost wrapper that achieves what I want (can be in any library)? Or must I use the technique I already know of custom cleanup function combined with a  weak_ptr?

Comment: What's magic about a reference count of one? Why would you potentially want to "clean up" an object when potentially one client is still holding on to it, isn't that going to cause problems for the client?

Comment: Sounds like you're doing some sort of cache manager...?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, as bdonlan says, it is a kind of a cache manager. The significance of 1 remaining is that the only copy remaining is the one in the cache itself.

Comment: Then is it not possible for the cache to hold `weak_ptr`s instead?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: If the one remaining reference is to the cash itself then I think that this may be your design issue. You could (should?) use `shared_ptr` to record only _external_ references to the object and hold on to a raw pointer or `weak_ptr` in the cache itself, then use a custom deleter to either pass the pointer back to the cache or merely to signal to the cache that the object no longer has external references rather than actually deleting the object.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, yes, I know that way, that's what I mention in the question. I'm just looking to use an easier way if there is one available.

Comment: @Luc, the reason not to use just weak_ptr's is because the object's lifetime should exist beyond all the shared_ptr's. The use pattern is that the objects will likely be requested quite quickly again so there is no reason to immediately drop them. Instead it waits a while.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: I don't understand. If you understand the easy way then why are you trying to do this the hard way?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, no, the weak_ptr/custom delete approach I consider the hard way in this circumstance. I'm looking for the easier way.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Perhaps you should embellish your question with some code and/or explain why you think it is hard. As far as I can see it is the simpler and more logical approach but you may have some design artifact that means that this isn't the case for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot in general accurately determine the number of references. But you can tell when it is exactly one - use `unique()`.

Comment: Well, let's hope this is faster than `use_count`.  I didn't notice this function, although it is right beside it in the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Destructively transform your `shared_ptr`s into `weak_ptr`s and then to `shared_ptr`s back again, except that some of those will be null. Of course there's no telling how that fares for performance, but given the interface we have it's either that or `use_count`.

Could look like:

```
std::for_each(begin, end, [](element_type& pointer)
{
    std::weak_ptr<element_type::element_type> weak = element_type(std::move(pointer));
    pointer = weak.lock();
});
auto predicate = [](element_type& pointer) { return !pointer; };
container.erase(std::remove_if(begin, end, predicate), end);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing something complex that can't quite be represented with the normal shared_ptr system, you might want to consider using [`intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) instead - your implementation of `intrusive_ptr_release` can then queue objects up for later destruction instead of deleting them immediately. Note that `intrusive_ptr` can't be directly used with `weak_ptr`, although you can construct your own variant of `weak_ptr` if you prefer. Keep in mind, though, that if you are using multiple threads the reference counting may get a bit tricky.

If you can't use an intrusive pointer, and it's acceptable to invalidate existing `weak_ptr`s when the last `shared_ptr` is lost, you can have the destructor for the `shared_ptr` put the *raw* pointer back into your cache (or whatever) marked for eventual cleanup. You can rewrap it in a `shared_ptr` the next time it is retrieved. However, again, this has the downside of losing all `weak_ptr`s to the object at the moment of pseudo-destruction.

If you can't use an intrusive pointer, you may be best off simply designing your own smart pointer implementation. Unfortunately, `shared_ptr` does not have the kind of hooks needed to implement your goals efficiently, so you may be working from scratch.

Comment: I don't think the intrusive pointer will work for me. The issue is that `intrusive_ptr_add_ref` is a free function, meaning essentially that each pointer of type belongs to the same global set. In my case it doesn't, and I think working around this would be as much work as a custom destructor, but less clean.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y, added some other suggestions

Comment: Yes, that's coming back to the method I know, of combining custom delete functions and weak_ptrs.  I was just hoping for some other easier implementation of this pattern -- I know it isn't hard though.